# object of type 'float' has no len() and image generation probelm

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am doing image classification and I am trying to increase my accuracy, that purpose  I am trying to generate image but, I got some file path error, please help me how to do.

here my code :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:\\Users\\NanduCn\\jupter1\\train-scene classification',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:\\Users\\NanduCn\\jupter1\\train-scene classification',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

I have 6 classes of images, but I got 1 class in image generation, here my files like this `train-scene classification is folder in train is images file and train.csv, and test.csv` .

```
Found 24335 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 24335 images belonging to 1 classes.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-faf37afc0119> in <module>()
     24         epochs=50,
     25         validation_data=0.25,
---> 26         validation_steps=800)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    131             else:
    132                 # Prepare data for validation
--> 133                 if len(validation_data) == 2:
    134                     val_x, val_y = validation_data
    135                     val_sample_weight = None

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: perhaps `validation_data=[0.25]?`

Comment: its validation for data

Comment: `taras` meant that `validation_data` should be a **list**, not a single value. You've updated the code but not the error output.

Comment: hi meowgoesthedog  I have 6 classes of images but, it showing 1 class, can you help me how to generate an image.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the stack trace you provide, `validation_data=0.25`.

Since `validation_data` is not a list-like object, it does not have `__len__` method, therefore, `len(validation_data)` generates an error.

It is not "some file path error", rather you need to ensure that `validation_data` is indeed what you think it is (some kind of a data-target value pair). Please check that.